# NullReferenceException when creating folder structure

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, io, directory

I'm having trouble creating a directory structure on initial loading of my game. I have a script that is supposed to create a set of folders if they do not exist, but I'm getting error:  `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object Loader.Start () (at Assets/_Scripts/Managers/Loader.cs:22)` I'm creating an array of the folders that I would like to create and then using a foreach to cycle through the array and using `Directory.CreateDirectory(path)` it should be creating the directory, but it's not. What am I doing incorrectly here?

***Loader.cs***

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;

public class Loader : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject gameManager;

    // File System List of Folders
    private List<string> folders;

    private void Awake ()
    {
        if (GameManager.Instance == null)
            Instantiate(gameManager);
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        // Create folder List
        folders.Add(Application.persistentDataPath + GameManager.animalDataFilePathRoot);
        folders.Add(Application.persistentDataPath + GameManager.animalDataFilePathJSON);
        folders.Add(Application.persistentDataPath + GameManager.animalDataFilePathTex);
        folders.Add(Application.persistentDataPath + GameManager.animalDataFilePathTemp);

        // If a folder doesn't exist, create it.
        foreach (string folder in folders)
        {
            CreateDirectory(folder);
        }
    }

    // Create Directory
    public void CreateDirectory(string path)
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            Debug.Log(path + " folder created.");
        }
        else if (Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            Debug.Log(path + " folder already exists.");
        }
    }
}
```

Variables in GameManager are set up like so:

```
public static string animalDataFilePathRoot { get; set; }
    public static string animalDataFilePathJSON { get; set; }
    public static string animalDataFilePathTex { get; set; }
    public static string animalDataFilePathTemp { get; set; }
    public static string animalDataFileNameJSON { get; set; }
    public static string animalDataFileNameTex { get; set; }

private void Start()
    {
        InitGameVariables();
    }

 void InitGameVariables()
    {
        animalDataFilePathRoot = "/animalData";
        animalDataFilePathJSON = "/animalData/json";
        animalDataFilePathTex = "/animalData/tex";
        animalDataFilePathTemp = "/animalData/tmp";
        animalDataFileNameJSON = "/animal.json";
        animalDataFileNameTex = "/animalTexture.png";
    }
```

Comment: Seems like you didnt initialize the instance of the Loader-Object. Write something like var loader = new Loader(); loader.Start();

Comment: Also initialize the folders variable by new List<string>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Initialize the `folders` variable before using it.

```
private List<string> folders = new List<string>();
```

Or do that in the Start function:

```
private List<string> folders;

private void Start()
{
    //Init
    folders = new List<string>();

    // Create folder List
    folders.Add(Application.persistentDataPath + GameManager.animalDataFilePathRoot);
    ...
    ...
}
```

---

Also, since you are using the variables from the `GameManager` class, in the `Start` function of the `Loader` class, it would make sense to initialize all those variables in the `GameManager`  class inside the `Awake` function instead of the `Start` function.

If you don't, `animalDataFilePathJSON` and other similar variables may not be initialized at the time they are used.

```
void Awake()
{
    InitGameVariables();
}
```